# An exam system of database,how to judge the correctness of a SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

My team and I are planning to do an online course exam database platform, The main task is judge SQL statements, but the question is How system judge the correctness of SQL statements submitted by students?

Especially for how to judge the establishment of a database structure, or stored procedures?

the system uses ASP.NET + SqlServer because it is an internal system so that you can ignore some efficiency issues; We mainly consider the judgment capacity of the system.

I hope you can give me some ideas, thank you.

Here is an example:

Q: Please Create a stored procedure to query all of the records in the table.

Students then enter SQL statements and submit, and the system will return the result of the judgement.

Comment: You run the SQL statement on the database and validate the results.  I don't think there is any other way.  This is how many on-line tutorials work, for a variety of different languages.

Comment: However, this method is only valid for the query statement

Comment: . . It is valid for any DDL or DML statement as well; you just have to be specific about what you are looking for, perhaps looking at metadata.

Comment: You'd have a testing database with a complete, comprehensive schema so that you can validate the statements against it. This is how, for example, all the MSDN sample statements work against the "AdventureWorks" database.

Comment: SQL Server has a way to execute a statement with a "noexec" option so that you can parse the statement without actually executing it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and help